# Is there a way to know how much Java heap space to set?

Tags: performance-tuning, export, memory, java, environment

I have already set it to be 4GB.

```
Needs["JLink`"]
ReinstallJava[JVMArguments -> "-Xmx4096m"]
```

However, when exporting a dataset to Excel sheet, I still get the following:
[image]

Very frsutrating after a long wait and still getting this error. My laptop does have 32G of RAM. But is there a way to figure out how much to set in advance (instead of setting to the limit)?

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say without `ans`.

Comment: At the very least, what does `ByteCount[Prepend[ans, Range[85]]]` return?

Comment: @J.M. Wow, it's 519284064. No idea it's that big!

Comment: Then, can you try setting to 8 GB (`ReinstallJava[JVMArguments -> "-Xmx8192m"]`)?

Comment: If you do not mind using NETLink (which seems way more efficient than JLink in the case of exporting large Excel files), try my bigExport function posted here: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1163363

Comment: @RolfMertig Might be a good way. Don't know why Wolfram is not using it. I am exporting three sheets in the same xlsx file. I don't know how to modify the code accordingly. There is no problem just exporting a single sheet. Thanks.

Comment: @RolfMertig It also requires some tuning for unequal length data. I got the error ""Objects of unequal length in {0,0}+{5000} cannot be combined"", most of my data are.

Comment: You should pad your data to be a list of equal lengths (with "" or 0 or so). more Sheets you can do by looping (Do loop) over Item[j]. I.e., check out what sheet=book@Worksheets@Item[1];  is doing. Try it yourself.